# .replacewith not working when called a second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have the following markup:

```
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Headline Events...</legend>

    <div style="width:100%; margin-top:10px;">
        <div style="width:100%; float:none;" class="clear-fix">
            <div style="width:400px; float:left; margin-bottom:8px;">
                <div style="width:150px; float:left; text-align:right; padding-top:7px;">
                    &nbsp;Team Filter:&nbsp;
                </div>
                <div style="width:250px; float:left;">
                    <input id="teamFilter" style="width: 100%" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="width:400px; float:left; margin-bottom:8px;">
                <div style="width:150px; float:left; text-align:right; padding-top:7px;">
                    &nbsp;Type Filter:&nbsp;
                </div>
                <div style="width:250px; float:left;">
                    <input id="typeFilter" style="width: 100%" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="diaryTable" name="diaryTable" class="clear-fix">
        Getting latest Headlines...
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I also have the following scripts

```
<script>

    function teamFilterChange(e) {
        //alert(this.value());
        setCookie('c_team', this.value(), 90);
        $c1 = getCookie('c_team');
        $c2 = getCookie('c_type');
        var param = "true|" + $c1 + "|" + $c2;
        outputHLDiaryEntries(param);
    }

    function typeFilterChange(e) {
        //alert(this.value());
        setCookie('c_type', this.value(), 90);
        $c1 = getCookie('c_team');
        $c2 = getCookie('c_type');
        var param = "true|" + $c1 + "|" + $c2;
        outputHLDiaryEntries(param);
    }

    // This optional function html-encodes messages for display in the page.
    function htmlEncode(value) {
        var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
        return encodedValue;
    }

    function outputHLDiaryEntries(param) {
        var url = "Home/DiaryEntries/";
        var data = "id=" + param;
        $.post(url, data, function (json) {
            var n = json.length;
            alert(n + ' ' + json);

            if(n == 0){
                //json is 0 length this happens when there were no errors and there were no results
                $('#diaryTable').replaceWith("<span style='color:#e00;'><strong>Sorry: </strong> There are no headline events found. Check your filters.</span>");

            } else {
                //json has a length so it may be results or an error message
                //if jsom[0].dID is undefined then this mean that json contains the error message from an exception
                if (typeof json[0].dID != 'undefined') {
                    //json[0].dDI has a value so we
                    //output the json formatted results 
                    var out = "";
                    var i;
                    var a = "N" //used to change the class for Normal and Alternate rows

                    for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

                        out += '<div class="dOuter' + a + '">';
                        out += '<div class="dInner">' + json[i].dDate + '</div>';
                        out += '<div class="dInner">' + json[i].dRef + '</div>';
                        out += '<div class="dInner">' + json[i].dTeam + '</div>';
                        out += '<div class="dInner">' + json[i].dCreatedBy + '</div>';
                        out += '<div class="dType ' + json[i].dType + '">' + json[i].dType + '</div>';
                        out += '<div class="dServer">' + json[i].dServer + '</div>';
                        out += '<div class="dComment">' + htmlEncode(json[i].dComment) + '</div></div>';

                        //toggle for normal - alternate rows
                        if (a == "N") {
                            a = "A";
                        } else {
                            a = "N";
                        }
                    }
                    //output our formated data to the diaryTable div
                    $('#diaryTable').replaceWith(out);

                } else {
                //error so output json string
                        $('#diaryTable').replaceWith(json);
                }
            }
        }, 'json');
    }


    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Set User Preferences
        //First check cookies and if null or empty set to default values
        var $c1 = getCookie('c_team');
        if ($c1 == "") {
            //team cookie does not exists or has expired
            setCookie('c_team', 'ALL', 90);
            $c1 = "ALL";
        }

        var $c2 = getCookie('c_type');
        if ($c2 == "") {
            //type cookie does not exists or has expired
            setCookie('c_type', "ALL", 90);
            $c2 = "ALL";
        }

        // create DropDownList from input HTML element
        //teamFilter
        $("#teamFilter").kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "SupportTeamText",
            dataValueField: "SupportTeamValue",
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: "Home/SupportTeams?i=1",
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        var teamFilter = $("#teamFilter").data("kendoDropDownList");
        teamFilter.bind("change", teamFilterChange);
        teamFilter.value($c1);

        //typeFilter
        $("#typeFilter").kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField: "dTypeText",
            dataValueField: "dTypeValue",
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: "Home/DiaryTypes?i=1",
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        var typeFilter = $("#typeFilter").data("kendoDropDownList");
        typeFilter.bind("change", typeFilterChange);
        typeFilter.value($c2);

        // Save the reference to the SignalR hub
        var dHub = $.connection.DiaryHub;

        // Invoke the function to be called back from the server
        // when changes are detected
        // Create a function that the hub can call back to display new diary HiLights.
        dHub.client.addNewDiaryHiLiteToPage = function (name, message) {
            // Add the message to the page.
            $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + htmlEncode(name)
                + '</strong>: ' + htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');
        };

        // Start the SignalR client-side listener
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            // Do here any initialization work you may need
            var param = "true|" + $c1 + "|" + $c2;
            outputHLDiaryEntries(param)
        });

    });
</script>
```

On initial page load the outputHLDiaryEntries function is called when the signalR hub is started. If I then change any of the dropdownlists this calls the outputHLDiaryEntries but the $('#diaryTable').replaceWith(); does not work. If I refresh the page the correct data is displayed.

**UPDATE!**

Based on A.Wolff's comments I fixed the issue by wrapping the content I needed with the same element I was replacing... by adding the following line at the beginning of the outputHLDiartEntries function...

```
var outStart = '<div id="diaryTable" name="diaryTable" class="clear-fix">';
var outEnd = '</div>';
```

and then changing each of the replaceWith so that they included the wrappers e.g.

```
$('#diaryTable').replaceWith(outStart + out + outEnd);
```

Comment: If you replace element, then it is no more in DOM and so next call to `$('#diaryTable')` will return empty matched set.... Maybe instead set its content, e.g using `html()`

Comment: @A.Wolff I didn't know that... what method can I use which could do this. If I were using aspx web pages I would have an update panel. Is there something similar in mvc?

Comment: @A.Wolff.... have I replaced the element or just the content within the element?

Comment: But it depends what you are looking for. I suggested to use [html(HTMLString)](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or you could replace element with other element having same ID

Comment: Using [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) you replace the element itself, not just its content

Comment: Understand... so I have replaced the whole element. If I always replace with my new content encapulated with the same element then it should work.

Comment: Ya, it should work indeed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) replaces element itself, so then on any next call to `$('#diaryTable')` will return empty matched set.

You best bet is to replace element's content instead, e.g:

```
$('#diaryTable').html("<span>New content</span>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with replaceWith() not working when called a second time.

This answer helped me figure out what I was doing wrong.

The change I made was assigning the same id to the new table I was creating.

Then when I would call my update function again, it would create a new table, assign it the same id, grab the previous table by the id, and replace it.

```
let newTable = document.createElement('table');
newTable.id = "sameId";

//do the work to create the table here

let oldTable = document.getElementById('sameId');
oldTable.replaceWith(newTable);
```